# Shiny server disconnecting apps

Tags: linux, shiny, shiny-server

We had shiny server running on an i686 machine under Ubuntu 16.04. After a recent upgrade server does not run the apps we were using to read and plot data from a MySQL database.

Now when we try to connect to our server the shiny app appears but in 1-2 seconds the screen goes to grey and a disconnected from server message appears
[image: screencapture of shiny app]

As there are no precompiled binaries for our system we have followed instructions to build from source at [Rstudio github site](https://github.com/rstudio/shiny-server/wiki/Building-Shiny-Server-from-Source). It apparently runs fine.

Shiny process is up and running

```
ps -ef | grep shiny
root     13596     1  0 10:19 ?        00:00:01 /usr/local/shiny-server/ext/node/bin/shiny-server /usr/local/shiny-server/lib/main.js --pidfile=/var/run/shiny-server.pid

status shiny-server
shiny-server start/running, process 13596
```

But at */var/log/shiny-server.log* this error message appears

> [2016-12-09 09:39:18.692][ERROR] shiny-server - Error getting worker: TypeError driver.validateOptions is not a function

Any idea of what happens with our server? Thanks in advance

Machine info:

> uname -a Linux rack4tb 4.4.0-47-generic #68-Ubuntu SMP Wed Oct 26
>   19:39:59 UTC 2016 i686 i686 i686 GNU/Linux

**EDIT**
Add output from history > serverHistory.txt

```
meteo@rack4tb:~$ tail -n 50 serverHistory.txt 
 1952  $PYTHON --version
 1953  cmake -DCMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=/usr/local -DPYTHON="$PYTHON" ../
 1954  shiny-server-1.4.2.0
 1955  make
 1956  mkdir ../build
 1957  (cd .. && ./bin/npm --python="$PYTHON" install)
 1958  (cd .. && ./bin/node ./ext/node/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/node-gyp/bin/node-gyp.js --python="$PYTHON" rebuild)
 1959  sudo make install
 1960  sudo ln -s /usr/local/shiny-server/bin/shiny-server /usr/bin/shiny-server
 1961  ls -l /usr/local/shiny-server/bin/shiny-server
 1962  ls -l /usr/bin/shiny-server
 1963  rm /usr/bin/shiny-server
 1964  sudo rm /usr/bin/shiny-server
 1965  sudo ln -s /usr/local/shiny-server/bin/shiny-server /usr/bin/shiny-server
 1966  sudo useradd -r -m shiny
 1967  sudo mkdir -p /var/log/shiny-server
 1968  sudo mkdir -p /srv/shiny-server
 1969  sudo mkdir -p /var/lib/shiny-server
 1970  sudo chown shiny /var/log/shiny-server
 1971  sudo mkdir -p /etc/shiny-server
 1972  cat /var/log/shiny-server
 1973  cd /var/log/shiny-server
 1974  ls -lrt
 1975  cd ..
 1976  ls
 1977  ls -lrt
 1978  cat shiny-server.log
 1979  /etc/mysql$ shiny-server --version
 1980  /etc/mysql shiny-server --version
 1981  shiny-server --version
 1982  uname -m
 1983  uname -a
 1984  ps -ef | grep shiny
 1985  sudo status shiny-server
 1986  status shiny-server
 1987  exit
 1988  cd /usr/local
 1989  ls
 1990  ls shiny-server/
 1991  ls shiny-server/bin
 1992  ls shiny-server/R
 1993  cat shiny-server/VERSION 
 1994  cd
 1995  ls
 1996  ls Descargas/
 1997  ls
 1998  ls shiny-server*deb
 1999  rm shiny-server*deb
 2000  exit
 2001  history > serverHistory.txt
```

Comment: What did you upgrade, I mean, the shiny server or the OS?

Comment: This seems to be a problem related to Shiny Server version 1.5.1.0...rolling back to version 1.4.2.0 seems to fix the issue.

Comment: As it was a production server no updates were scheduled for Os. Now we have updated first OS and then shiny server. Is version 1.4.2.0 available for download?

Comment: Following your question `After a recent upgrade server does not run the apps`...what does that mean?

Comment: What I tried to explain, the app shows for 1-2 seconds but before you can select any input (buttons, lists,...) from ui.R the screen goes to grey (see picture in the post) and no action can be taken.

Comment: Open a terminal and type the following command: `history > serverHistory.txt` and post the content of the last 50 lines of that file

Comment: @pacomet , any resolution of this problem. I am struggling with a very similar issue.

Comment: @AlexanderRadev We could not find a solution nor build shiny server again in the old machine. Now it is running in a new machine with the most recent versions.

Comment: @AlexanderRadev, how did you solve your issue? I came across a similar problem as well

Comment: @OscarMontoya We did not find a solution. Please see the comment before. We needed to move to another newest machine.

Answer (score 0):

What worked for me was to launch `sudo R` and install all packages the app needs:

```
sudo su - -c "R -e \"install.packages('package_name', repos = 'http://cran.rstudio.com/',dependencies =TRUE)\""
```